# Do any websites except RailEurope allow making reservations for Eurail Pass Holders?

Tags: online-resources, eurail

I am a Eurail Global Pass holder. Is RailEurope my only option, if I am to try and purchase all bookings 'under one roof'? Some sites of local operators, as listed by seat61.com, aren't easy to navigate.

Comment: Which countries are you plannning or hoping to travel in?

Comment: The Netherlands, Belgium, France, Germany, Czech Republic, Denmark.

Comment: I would start with the German site: https://www.bahn.com/en/view/index.shtml Select 'reservation only'.

Comment: Bahn.com didn't work for me. They're saying they are not selling the reservation I am looking for. I've booked everything via raileurope.com now, save Hamburg to Copenhagen. Rail Europe isn't offering that to me. Any leads would be appreciated? I asked a question specific to that, but it rubbed somebody the wrong way.

Comment: I have tried again. Bahn.de and raileurope.com are selling tickets for Hamburg to Copenhagen, but when I select reservation only, Rail Europe gives me no results and DB Bahn says Reservation Impossible. Can anyone help?

Comment: It might be that the allotment of reservations for Rail passes are all used up. It might be that you did not select something you should have and it might be something I have not thought about. I would contact Bahn, they are the best company for this travel with the Danish one. I am sure they have a telephone number or e-mail option on their site.

Answer (score 1):

According to Mark Smith on his Man in Seat 61 web site (which I have usually found reliable) the issue is that DB only lets you do reservation-seat-only for domestic journeys and you want an international one. Here is [more info](https://www.seat61.com/Railpass-and-Eurail-pass-guide.htm#How_to_make_reservations_with_a_railpass) from his site.